# php Object Class Error: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, object

I get the following error `Creating default object from empty value...` each time I attempt to add a nested object.

```
class api {

    private $authentication=null;
    private $status=null;
    private $response=null;

    public function __construct($user, $token) {
        $this->status->version=2.3; 
        $this->authentication->user=$user;
        $this->authentication->token=$token;
    }

}
```

How can I accomplish this exact thing without getting this error?

I don't want to use arrays for this particular thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this help you or am I misunderstanding...

```
public function __construct($user, $token) {
    $this->status = new stdClass(); // Here
    $this->status->version=2.3; 
    $this->authentication = new stdClass(); // & Here
    $this->authentication->user=$user;
    $this->authentication->token=$token;
}
```

Comment: OK, my bad. Updated, but does it work?

Comment: Yes it does work. Thanks. But can you explain why I have to do this?

Comment: My understanding here is that `$this->status` and `$this->authentication` are set to null (not an object) so you have to cast them to an object first before assigning properties to them.

Comment: How would I cast them to objects?

Comment: Just handle it in the constructor as per my answer for convenience.